Haftarah at Shabbat Minchah?
In the book A Voice Still Heard: The Sacred Songs of the Ashkenazic Jews by Professor Eric Werner, I found this passage that does not match usual practice as I have seen it or as any of my siddurim have printed:

The close organic intertwining — indeed the inseparability of musical and liturgical traditions in minhag ashkenaz — may be demonstrated with one telling instance: in the minhah service of the Sabbath there is a special passage called the kedusha de-sidra (beginning with the Words "u-va le-tziyon go'el" [a redeemer shall come to Zion] and continuing with a number of scriptural verses). According to a Gaonic principle this kedusha de-sidra was to be sung to a melody used by students when reciting the sidrah (Torah lesson). Elsewhere, in a rarely observed decree, R. Saadyah Gaon had listed all those scriptural verses in which the community is expected to join the reader of the lesson. Among the verses listed are those quoted in the kedusha de-sidra[15]. This is probably related to the fact that in the Sabbath minhah of minhag ashkenaz the cantillation of the Haftarah (Prophetic lesson) dominates the chant of the entire service. If this conjecture is valid, it should apply also to passages from the liturgy of public fast days, which surround the nucleus Exodus 34:6-7, 32:11-14, 34:1-10. On those days, following Saadyah Gaon's prescribed list, Exodus 32:13 and 34:6 are chanted by the entire congregation. When we turn to the actual chant (example 3) we discover that it is a direct derivative from the cantillation of the Prophetic lesson. There is also an additional prayer for these fast days (example 4), inserted into the thirteenth benediction of the Amidah, which is chanted in the same mode as the Sabbath minhah service.
 
15. Teshubot ha-Ge'onim, ed. Harkavy (Berlin, 1887), no. 308, Hebrew text, p. 310. See also Rashi, in Likkute ha-pardes (Polna, 1813), p. 9, and Geonica (op. cit.), where one reads:
בטעמן שהתינוקות קורין לפני רבן

What is bothering me about the logic of this passage is "in the Sabbath minhah of minhag ashkenaz the cantillation of the Haftarah (Prophetic lesson) dominates the chant of the entire service." I have never heard a Haftarah recited on Sabbath afternoon, or on any afternoon except for fast days. I am familiar with the new week's Torah reading at minhah, the transplanting of kedusha de-sidra from the morning to the afternoon, but it has not been the practice anywhere I have been to read a Haftarah at this point. I am not at all clear which Haftarah one would choose either. No siddurim I have checked mention a Haftarah here (for example Artscroll p. 512). I don't think this professor dreamed this occurance up, but I would be equally surprised if this was a custom that used to be done and has seemingly disappeared. Can anyone explain it?

There indeed once was a haftara at mincha on shabbat https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31437/759 but I'm guessing he just means the musical mode of haftara is the same one as that of shabbat mincha

@DoubleAA, I think it's more coincidental that the modalities are similar between haftarah and minchah for Shabbos (in both Eastern and Western Ashkenazi usage)

@Noach certainly, I didn't mean to imply any causation

@DoubleAA, nor did I understand you as such. I read the author quoted in OP to understand  causal link
